Tableau window calculations will only accept aggregated values
I have a dataset where every row has a datetime and a value. What I am trying to do with Tableau is to calculate the rolling average and rolling stdev of said value for the past 7 days. I am not able to achieve that due to Tableau's moving calculation that can only work with aggregated values. WINDOW_AVG(AVG([Value]),-7,0) is calculating the moving average of the daily average which is different from the actual average for the past 7 days.
I was able to get a work around by doing WINDOW_SUM(SUM([Value]))/WINDOW_SUM(COUNT([Value])) to calculate the rolling average. However, for the rolling stdev, I couldn't devise a method to calculate the rolling stdev for the past 7 days using a similar fashion as the formula for stdev is alot more complicated that averages.
I have also found alot of forum talking about using LOD expressions to calculate them, but I am not familiar with it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance Tableau experts!
